# What is the Correct Shell Function Code to Open a File Type

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone please help with problem running code below. It works when I specify only 1 filename in the Shell function but when I try a loop, whereby I want Shell to simply be a file opener of file type specified (ie .sim), the system loops endlessly; opening the .exe and presenting a dialogue box from opened executable program "file doesn't exist".

Background: I've many .sim files in a folder that I want to perform an execution using code inside loop below. Once the task for first opened .sim file is complete I want to loop through all remaining .sim files.

Xidgel I try this and it works well only once and then trying again it fails;

```
Sub Test1()
Dim strProgramName As String
Dim Foldername As String
Dim Fname As String

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = False
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
strProgramName = "C:\userspath.exe"
Foldername = "C:\whatever\"
Fname = Dir(Foldername & "*.sim")

Do While Len(Fname)
wsh.Run strProgramName & " " & Foldername & Fname, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
SendKeys "(%)m"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
SendKeys "{DOWN 13}"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
SendKeys "(^S)"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
SendKeys "%{F4}"
Fname = Dir()
Loop
MsgBox "Task Complete!"
End Sub
```

Comment: At the end of your loop don't you need to call Dir() again, but with no args, to return the next file?

Comment: Thanks Xidgel. I added DIR but an error occurs on the Shell line. How can I code the Shell line to open the exe and not a specific file but the first file it finds in the folder with the specified extension (then my routine is performed) then the next file of same extension in the folder specified (ie Foldername) is loaded etc until all files of the given extension are executed?

Comment: If you can call path.exe with arguments then something like `Shell "C:\users-apps\path.exe C:\Users\path\" & Fname, vbHide` might work. If your paths contain spaces or other funny business you might need to carefully use double-quotes --- see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917355/how-do-you-run-a-exe-with-parameters-using-vbas-shell)

Comment: Thanks again Xidgel. Yes I saw the question at the link you gave (ie How do you run a .exe with parameters using vba's shell()?). I playes with it but still have a problem. I have added the revised code below

Comment: Thanks Xidgel. I tried suggestions but still problem. I have now;
Dim strProgramName As String
Dim Foldername As String
Dim Fname As String
    strProgramName = "C:\userspath.exe"
    Foldername = "C:\whatever\"
    Fname = Dir(Foldername & "*.sim")
    Do While Len(Fname)
    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & Fname & """")
    ROUTINE
    Fname = Dir()
Loop
But when exe opens a dialogue box error says; "Not all files specified on the command line exist. The files which could not be found are;". But the files it says don't exist are there in the folder. Any thoughts?

Comment: Xidgel I reposted the code above for easier vieiwng. Sorry I'm new to SO.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me (sending text and commands to a series of files edited using Notepad):

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim Foldername As String
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim TaskID As Variant

    strProgramName = "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
    Foldername = "C:\temp\"
    Fname = Dir(Foldername & "*.dat")
    Do While Len(Fname)
        ' Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & Fname & """")
        TaskID = Shell(strProgramName & " " & Foldername & Fname, vbNormalFocus)
        AppActivate TaskID

        Application.SendKeys "ABC" & vbCr, True  ' Add some text
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")

        Application.SendKeys "^s", True  ' CTRL-s = save
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")

        Application.SendKeys "%{F4}", True  ' Alt-F4 = Quit
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")

        ' Get next file
        Fname = Dir()
    Loop
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"
End Sub
```

For me use of `SendKeys` was a little fragile. I needed the call to `AppActivate` to make sure the keystrokes were directed to Notepad. I first tried the `Shell` command without using `vbNormalFocus` and only some of my keystrokes made it through to Notepad. Also, when I tried to run the code from the VBA environment the keystrokes got sent to Excel, so I had to test by running from Excel.

Hope this get you started.

Comment: Xidgel your Shell opens exe but first routine quickly initiates and somehow seems there no time avail for actual file to open first. Routine then completes with just exe open (ie routines performed on an empty exe without any file loaded). Send keys work but designated file hasn’t been opened or is and sits somewhere in background due maybe to timing between exe open and routine start.

Comment: Xidgel I add last bit of information here; you can use wsh (wait on shell) so I assembled code above. Works perfect but strangely it only runs when waitOnReturn Boolean is False (Stack recommendation was use True…when I use true the file opens but no send keys run). Then I change True to False and it runs only once. Try running again and the exe is opened, the send keys get sent to the exe and then file opens etc. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762566/vba-wscript-shell-run-exe-file-with-parameter
Oh I bought Walkenbach VBA book. Hope it helps me. Any further help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `WScript`, so I don't know how to help you. If you want to keep trying `Shell`, then I would suggest debugging one step at a time. (a) get your code to successfully open a file --- you may need to experiment by increasing the wait time (say if your files are big/take a long time to open), inserting a wait between the call to `Shell` and `AppActivate`, etc.; (b) once you can open a file, see if you can close it; (c) when open and close work, then send some key strokes to edit; (d) then add a save, etc. That's how I got the Notepad example to work.

Comment: Thanks xidgel. OK I solved the problem using your approach. Slowly I found I needed to remove the `windowStyle` and `waitonReturn` as I was already using a timing sysem with the `Application.WaitNow` and `SendKeys`. But now I have many files to process and it is very slow because the exe. is running on the screen and I think this is sloing things down. Have tried `Application.DisplayAlerts=False``Application.ScreenUpdating=False` etc but no luck yet. If you know of any ways I can speed up the process I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: What is the "bottleneck" (slowest part) of your process? If your files are large and take a long time to open and/or a long time to save, then no amount of code optimization will speed that up. If it takes a long time to start your .exe, then maybe you could modify the code to start it once, then send it the names of files to open/edit/save/close. On the other hand, if the bottleneck is the VBA code, your can try reducing the wait times. But that could be risky --- `SendKeys` seems to be somewhat unreliable without the wait times. You may need some other tool like dynamic data exchange (DDE).

Comment: Xidgel thankyou again. Bottleneck is opening/closing of exe each time for each individual file. That's how I've currently coded this macro but you made me realise that's not good. OK I'll look into maybe re-coding the shell function command line. I think somehow I need to break out the opening/closing routine form the shell I guess such that the exe only opens once and then each file is opened from within the alreasdy opened exe. Any thoughts on that appreciated. And I don't know DDE. Heard about it and will check it out online. Would it be easy to implement into my current VBA code? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

OK Here's a new version that opens the .exe **once**, opens/edits/saves/closes a series of files, then closes the .exe. I hope is closer to a solution.

```
Public Sub send_keys_test_2()
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim Foldername As String
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim TaskID As Variant

    ' In version 1 I tested with Notepad
    ' This version won't work with Notepad because it assumes
    ' a multiple document interface (MDI). Specifically, we want
    ' an .exe that can be open without having documents open. Notepad
    ' fails this requirement --- if you close a document in Notepad
    ' then the Notepad application closes too. So in this version
    ' I will test with MS Word.
    ' Modify to suit your purposes.
    strProgramName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.exe"

    ' My test files are in C:\temp
    ' Modify to suit your purposes
    Foldername = "C:\temp\"

    ' My test files are a series of Word Docs
    ' Modify to suit your purposes
    Fname = Dir(Foldername & "File*.doc")

    ' If there are no matching files, then exit
    If Len(Fname) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    ' Otherwise, start the .exe WITHOUT opening any files
    TaskID = Shell(strProgramName, vbNormalFocus)

    ' Allow plenty of time for the .exe to open
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")

    ' Make sure the keystrokes get sent to the .exe
    AppActivate TaskID

    Do While Len(Fname)
        ' Call Shell to open the first file
        ' In Word, send CTRL-o to display the file open dialog box
        ' Then send the Foldername + FName
        ' Then send an ENTER key to complete the file open
        ' Modify this to suit your purposes
        Application.SendKeys "^o", True                 ' CTRL-o = open
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
        Application.SendKeys Foldername & Fname, True   ' Send the file name
        Application.SendKeys "~", True                  ' Send {Enter} to close dialog, open file

        ' Now edit the file
        ' For demo purposes, just send a few new chars
        Application.SendKeys "ABC" & vbCr, True         ' Add some text

        ' Save the file
        ' In Word, send CTRL-s
        ' Modify to suit your purposes
        Application.SendKeys "^s", True  ' save

        ' Close the file
        ' In Word, send CTRL-w
        ' Modify to suit your purposes
        Application.SendKeys "^w", True  ' save

        ' Get next file
        Fname = Dir()
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
    Loop

    ' Send the quit command
    ' In Word, send Alt-F4
    ' Modify to suit your purposes
    AppActivate TaskID
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
    Application.SendKeys "%{F4}", True  ' Alt-F4 = Quit

    MsgBox "Task Complete!"
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.