# Run .command file from Excel VBA with Shell

Tags: excel, vba, macos, shell, terminal

I wanted to run terminal .command file with script from Excel VBA Macro. I found out that I can use

`Shell ("/Users/user/path/to/file/test.command")`

but it throws an error

`“test.command” can’t be opened because Microsoft Excel is not allowed to open documents in Terminal.`

Is there any way to allow Excel to run Terminal commands?

I saw an option to change `.command` to `.sh` and run with `chmod +x`, but it does not do anything (no error, no result). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which kind of file do you want to run? Try this: `"Line 1:Sub test() Line 2:Dim RetVal
Line 3:RetVal = Shell("C:\Windows\System32\CMD.EXE", 1)
Line 4:End Sub"`. That one will run Console.

Comment: You create the shell object and then run that, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34012511/10645228

Comment: Thanks, forgot to specify - I'm looking for a solution for a MacOS. probably that's different there.